# Save UITextField everytime user scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

My issue is, i have 5 UIViewController that i put all in one UIScrollView. In each viewcontroller i have some UITextField that i need the text to be saved to NSUserDefaults.
I'm able to do it using button, but how do i save it everytime the user scroll to next view?(without any button?)
Thanks..
This is the working code i'm using for the first viewcontroller

```
- (void)save:(id)sender {
    NSString *a_name1 = [name text];
    NSString *a_address = [address text];
    NSString *a_address2 = [address2 text];
    NSString *a_age = [age text]

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:a_name1 forKey:@"name"];
    [defaults setObject:a_address forKey:@"address"];
    [defaults setObject:a_address2 forKey:@"address2"];
    [defaults setObject:a_age forKey:@"age"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a delegate to the scroll view and implement `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` or `scrollViewDidScroll:` and check the contentOffset to see if you changed page.

If at that point you detect that you changed page, you can then do whatever you need to do

Comment: Hi, thanks, i use the code below
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((scroller.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)+1;
pager.currentPage = page;
self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page];
NSLog(@"the page:%@",self.title);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contentoffset` property of the scrollview to find the current visible view(or VC) and use it to do the process

Implement along with the scrollview delegates you can achieve this

Answer (score -1):

it don't seem very useful to create for every UITextField a ViewController. If i had understand your question correctly you need only on UIViewController instance. Add the UITextField-objects on the view property of the viewController instance (overwrite the viewDidLoad method or add them in the Interfacebuilder.
If your deployment target iOS 6 implement the viewDidDisapear: method and overwrite the method with your NSUserDefaults code from above. if your deployment older then iOS 6 you can overwrite the viewDidUnload method.